# slow down computer when i installing something

Tags: windows-7, installation, performance

Every time I just go to the process of installing something (game or software, but game is more) my speed of computer goes down!

It's not important what I opened, it need much time to open. I have Windows 7 64-bit and my CPU is AMD Athlon 2 x4 635, 4gb ram, my gpu is hd radeon 5870 asus, and power is green 785B.

When I install something for example a game, my RAM go to max 2GB working, and CPU so little. I can't understand why!  I just defragment my hard disk, after uninstall a game. Is anyone has idea why?

Comment: @sathya: dude, it's about shutting down the system. but my question is about SLOW down the system!?!?!? they solution is about changing hardware and something about heating issue. if there is my answer, just say where is it.

Comment: the linked duplicate is your answer. It's slowing down due to overheating

Comment: but i have too much fans in my computer, and if it's about heating , why when i play for example hitman in high setting i dont have any problem?

Comment: in that case how about you [edit] your question and add more details such as full specifications, pwoer supply, GPU, temperatures etc? There's no way to answer properly with the details you've provided

Comment: if anything else needed, just say to me. but i think it's must be something in windows or hard disk. but about heating, i just checked it when i played absolution,heating in high of it was about 70 or 71 and in game normally was 65 or 68.(i speak about my gpu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing an application is taxing on the hard drive. Launching other applications simultaneously will appear as slow because the hard drive will be busy installing (writing) thus unable to dedicate it's full power to reading.

The bottleneck of any system is usually the hard drive (gaming put aside). Many people tend to forget that, because marketing emphasizes CPU and GPU performance. A description of a computer in a magazine will usually mention only the capacity of a hard drive and nothing about model, brand or performance.

If your disc is a year old or older, it is fully possible that it has performance problems due to the fact that it is worn out.

Run something like Crystal Disk Mark when your computer is idle to get an idea of how the disk is doing. Compare your results with the nominal performance numbers from the manufacturer and benchmark results by independent reviewers. You can usually figure out which hard drive you have in the windows device manager.

Comment: your information is true, i have 2 hard drives , but one of them (200gb) are older than other (500gb), and my windows is on old one. so have you any idea for improve the performance? i think , i must change my hard drives or change the location of windows. any way thanks for your answer. i accept it, cuz i think your answer help me find out my problem.

Comment: Run some kind of diagnostic application on your drives. Search for "hdd benchmarking" or "S.M.A.R.T health monitoring" application. If you see warnings in the SMART tool, consider throwing the drive out all together. Otherwise, If you get very slow read and write speeds (~20 MB/s write and ~60 MB/s read) then the drive is just old and needs to be replaced. Unfortunately no tips on how to make it run faster - a wild guess would be the cable is bad, but that is not very common, although possible...